# Bridge ethernet connection wireless from switch to tablet

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm experiencing a major problem and I thought of this silly question. I have a 5 port switch connected to the company's Ethernet cable. I have a printer and a PC connected to that switch. We also have 2 access points in this huge building, but unfortunately our intranet WiFi sucks! and the inspectors are using tablets to connect to the WiFi and the signal keeps falling and breaking. Our Network Administrators are out of state and I don't have access to the routers credentials. Is there a type of bridge adapter that I can connect to one of the switch ports so I can receive internet from there to our tablets? instead of connecting to the routers or Access Points. I just finished developing a program for Quality Control and the signal from the routers is too far and the switch/hub I'm talking about is right there at the quality control area.

Thank you so much for your help guys, I gladly appreciate it

Comment: Most wireless routers will perform this function.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what an access point (or "wireless router" in layman's terms) *is*.

To use a typical home gateway wireless router as a plain bridging access point, just disable its DHCP Server feature and plug one of its LAN ports into your switch.